# How to retrieve data from MYSQL database hosted on Azure VM?

Tags: java, mysql, web-services, tomcat, azure

I'm a software engineering student and I need your help.

I have developped a dynamic web project (Java ee/JSF/Hibernate/MySQL/Apache Tomcat/Eclipse) and I have deployed it on windows azure. I actually created a virtual machine where I installed MySQL and Tomcat.

My problem is:

> How can I retreive data from my Database hosted on the VM to process
>   some actions on?

I thought about REST WS project from wich I will invoke some services, but I don't know what services are exposed or how to do the connection to DB.(I need something free)

I'm blocked and your help will be more than appreciated .

Best regards.

Comment: Please help :( Any hint may be useful !

Answer (score 0):

One option is, instead of hosting the database on the VM, You could create Mysql on Azure as shown here - http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/store-php-create-mysql-database/

Also, now Azure Websites now supports Java Web Applications - you can deploy your Tomcat Application to Azure Websites as shown here - http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-java-get-started/